# How historically accurate was the movie "Charlie Wilson's War"?

Tags: united-states, cold-war

I am watching, and really enjoying, the movie, "Charlie Wilson's War".

How historically accurate is this movie?

- Did Charlie Wilson play as big as role as is portrayed?
- Is the movie accurate regarding Russia's activities in Afghanistan?

Thanks

Comment: Genuinely interested, can somebody explain why this is a bad question, and how I can improve?

Comment: Patience; research takes time.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Cool :) Posted the question and received an instant downvote, thought I had done something wrong!

Comment: Can you give a brief description of what this movie is about and how it relates to your question? As it stands, it would be impossible to answer your question without being familiar with the movie.

Comment: Huh? Why would anyone who isn't familiar with the movie would even attempt at answering the question @congusbongus?

Comment: Not my downvote, but it'd be more generally useful to the community, if the question elaborates on the film portrayal of Charlie Wilson and Russian activities. It'd also help focus the question, and perhaps someone familiar with [Operation Cyclone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Cyclone) but didn't watch the movie could weigh in too.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: The concept of "historical accuracy" is suspect, though I suspect you're using it as a proxy for "history as practiced by historians."  Fictive films never meet the standards of historiography as works of history.  In particular, this film's Whiggish moralising, simplification, and biographic fixation make the film's "accuracy" a trivial: of course not.

Answer (score 5):

It was [Zbigniew Brzezinski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zbigniew_Brzezinski) who was the real architect. It was his grand strategy to deliver to the Soviets what he called the "Soviet Vietnam".

It was Zbigniew Brzezinski who wanted to engage the Soviets but faced opposition on the home front when it came to funding and supply of weapons.

In comes [Charlie Wilson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Wilson_%28Texas_politician%29), a flamboyant cowboy with a boyish charm and a lot of contacts with lobbyists, evangelists and Senators. He took an unusually high interest in Afghanistan even when many of his own partymen concentrated their efforts on Central America and the drug wars. He was discreetly called in by the Reagan administration.

It was Zbigniew Brzezinski's brains with Charlie Wilson's charms coupled with [Avrokatos'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gust_Avrakotos) team's analytical skills and planning and detailing of the plans.

There is another figure who was ignored that was a guy called Raymond Casey who pulled all the strings to make all this possible. He pulled up an unwilling or rather incapabale CIA to pool their resources to support the Mujahiddeen. He didn't play any role in the actual strategic decisions though.

The movie portrays the defeat of the Soviets as Charlie Wilson's idea from start to finish. He was a just one of the big team who made all this possible. In fact, he was a tool in the hands of Zbigniew Brzenzski who lacked his charm and contacts.

Charlie Wilson is potrayed as a lone ranger figure taking on the Indians all by himself. The movie isn't complete fantasy. But it was a cowboy movie in a political drama setting with a fake hero. The real heroes were Zbigniew Brzezinski and Raymond Casey.

Comment: We generally prefer our answers to have more than two words. Even if they are big ones with lots of Zs.

Comment: Sorry, -1 for now. Please expand the answer and I will be happy to reverse my vote.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Looks like the answer has been expanded now, I gave an upvote, interesting stuff

Comment: well, I wanted to gather more information in the meantime so I just reserved my place

Comment: Okay, I upvoted now (but it'd be better to have a source too).

Comment: http://www.globalresearch.ca/hollywoods-dangerous-afghan-illusion-charlie-wilsons-war/5331107